# Formal-sounding yet incorrect construction

Tags: single-word-requests

I discovered several years ago that there is a word for the grammar mistakes some people make when they try (perhaps subconsciously) to sound *more formal*  or *grand* in their speech but simply end up with something that sounds grand to *them*, yet clearly wrong to grammar aficionados. I subsequently forgot this word and have been unable to find it again. Can anyone help me? (Hint: It's not *malapropism*)

Comment: Hypercorrection? Such as "Please have dinner with my husband and I" or "Please contact John and myself"?

Comment: @curious-proofreader that may be it. Thanks!

Comment: @suməlic I would agree.

Answer (score 1):

The general term for the phenomenon is [*hypercorrection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection):

> A **non-standard usage** that results from the over-application of a perceived rule of grammar or a usage prescription. A speaker or writer who produces a hypercorrection generally believes that the form is correct through misunderstanding of these rules, often combined with a desire to appear formal or educated.

[Per the linked Wikipedia article]

Answer (score 0):

The *general* term for mistakes based on attempts to conform to an often illusory 'correctness' is 'overcorrection'.

> **overcorrect**
>   *v.tr.*
>   To correct beyond what is needed, appropriate, or usual, especially when resulting in a mistake.
>   *v.intr.*
>   To correct something to an excessive or unusual degree.
>   **overcorrection**, *n.*

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "overcorrection." Retrieved August 25 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overcorrection.)

The equivalent *specialized technical* term in linguistics is 'hypercorrection'.

> **hypercorrection** *n.*
>   1. A construction or pronunciation produced by mistaken analogy with standard usage out of a desire to be correct, as in the substitution of I for me in *on behalf of my parents and I*.
>   2. The production of such a construction or pronunciation.

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "hypercorrection." Retrieved August 25 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypercorrection.)

While 'hypercorrection' is undoubtedly used with the colloquial *general* sense of 'overcorrection', it is ironic that such use is an example of itself in the lexical domain.